# Group rows together while summing one column

Tags: excel, sum, grouping, rows, excel-2013

I have large dataset in excel (2013) in which I'm trying to group values together.

Data:

```
A - A - A - 4
B - B - B - 5
A - A - A - 2 
C - C - C - 3
B - B - B - 8
```

Desired output

```
A - A - A - 6
B - B - B - 13
C - C - C - 3
```

How do I do this?

Comment: a) Use a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) in column E then copy and Paste Special, Values to remove the formulas. b) delete column D c) Data ► Remove Duplicates.

Comment: @djN, just use a [Pivot Table](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the the hyphens are meant to represent cell boundaries, I'm not convinced that a PivotTable, fan of those as I am, is the best solution because although it would give the results the format would not match the `Desired output` very closely. So instead I suggest Subtotal. Label `Data` (say `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`), hence assuming `4` is in D2, select A1 to Dn (where `n` represents the last relevant row) DATA > Outline - Subtotal

At each change in: `one`,
Use function: Sum,
Add subtotal to: check `four`,
check Replace current subtotals and Summary below data,
OK.

Delete the Grand Total row and filter to select, for ColumnA, Text Filters, Contains..., `tot`, OK. In the lowest numbered row where **`Total`** is visible enter:

```
=Am
```

where `m` represent the one less than the row number of that cell. Copy across to ColumnC and down to suit. Remove the filter and select instead the second level group (click on a small `2` to the left of the column Headings).